# Sending Email using MD5 Challenge-Response Authentication

Tags: smtp

I'm trying to send email using MD5 Challenge Response, but it is not working with me, here's the code I am trying:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mMsg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("bshouman@gmail.com", "bshouman@gmail.com", "test", "test");
mMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpC = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();   
smtpC.Host = "mail.***.com";
smtpC.Port = 465;
smtpC.EnableSsl = true;
smtpC.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
System.Net.NetworkCredential creds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sales@***.com", "***", "***.com");
smtpC.Credentials = creds.GetCredential("mail.***.com", 465, "CRAM-MD5"); ;
smtpC.Send(mMsg);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

Comment: Sounds like the error is unrelated to the authentication mechanism. Perhaps you need to explicitly tell the SmtpClient to use SSL/TLS (since you connect to port 465)?

Comment: @user290611 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx

Comment: man look at my code SSL is enabled

Comment: I was looking around and I found that I need to use System.Web.Mail, any idead how to MD5 authenticate with it